# Laravel User registration after unsuccessful authorization

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-5, authorization

In `Laravel 5.6` you need to do the following.

There is an authorization `form - processes` the `LoginController`, in my case I changed the email to name, and the password remained.

If such a user is with such a password, then I authorize it, and if the user does not have such a name and password, then it is necessary to register with the data that was entered.

Here is the class `LoginController`

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;


class LoginController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Login Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles authenticating users for the application and
    | redirecting them to your home screen. The controller uses a trait
    | to conveniently provide its functionality to your applications.
    |
    */

    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after login.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/';
    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    }

    protected function redirectTo()
    {
        return '/';
    }

    public function username() {
        return 'name';
    }

    /**
     * Handle a failed authorization attempt.
     *
     * @return void
     *
     * @throws \Illuminate\Auth\Access\AuthorizationException
     */


    protected function sendFailedLoginResponse(Request $request)
    {
        // What you need to do to register a user

    }
}
```

I thought to override `sendFailedLoginResponse` to register the user at that moment. Run as a `RegisterController` and transfer data from the `POST` request.

Tell me how to implement this idea?

Comment: You could try redirecting the user to the registration screen with all the inputs he sent you and assign it there. But I am somehow suspicious of systems that send my data one place or another. Generally, the password of a user should not be in transit in a system. It should be checked and forgotten. (Or saved and forgotten).  But I have a question, what if you had a typo in your login?

Comment: - But I have a question, what if you had a typo in your login? It does not matter in this task. Simply if there is no such user, then we create. I think this approach will be bad. It is necessary at the backend level to organize registration without redirects.

Comment: Well, I'm not against new approaches in general. But one has to consider the impact of something like this. In a sense, you could be indicating to a user that he doesn't have an account if he simply forgot his login. At some point you would be bound to have similar users because they forgot their initial password, which, by the way, might be safer using an email. But I understand, you have to do what's assigned to you. I'm gonna make a test on my own application later and let you know.

Answer (score 0):

1.) Open file : `Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticateUsers.php`
2.) Search for the method : login 
3.) Edit return `$this->sendFailedLoginResponse($request);` to

```
return url('/register?username='.$request->username.'&password='.Hash::make($password));
```

This is the simplest way but not the best one, the best practice would be not to send password via get, or not to set somewhere else from database..

Answer (score 0):

Such an implementation in my opinion is not entirely correct. I realized like this

```
 public function login(Request $request)
 {
    $this->validate($request, [
        'name' => 'required|string',
        'password' => 'required|string'
    ]);
    $user = User::firstOrCreate([
        'name' => $request->name
    ], [
        'name' => $request->name,
        'password' => Hash::make($request->password)
    ]);

    if ($user && Hash::check($request->password, $user->password)) {
        auth()->loginUsingId($user->id);
        return redirect()->intended('/');
    } else {
        throw ValidationException::withMessages([
            $this->username() => [trans('auth.failed')],
        ]);
    }
 }
```